# cannot update a record Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

```
public class QuoteRequest implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long quoteRequestId = null;
```

}

```
quoteRequestEntity = quoteRequestDao.update(quoteRequestEntity);
```

I am getting the above error when i am trying to update my quote request. I do not undersatnd what is wrong in my mapping. Can somebody please help.

Comment: I think this means your update isn't running work. You need check your `quoteRequestEntity`.

Comment: can you show us how you populate your `quoteRequestEntity` Object.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because `quoteRequestId` is **null**.

you should set a value on your `quoteRequestId` because when you **UPDATE** your entity, it will not generate an ID on it, it will generate only when you **INSERT** a record.